# Listing the contains of a tar incremental archive for each day with all of the changes from previous days

Tags: linux, backup, tar, incremental

I need to make tar incremental archives for each day. I am using the following command:

`tar -cz --listed-incremental=/home/Backup/list.snar --file=/home/Backup/$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tar.gz -C /home/ Files`

When extracting day by day till the day I need, at the end I have a directory with all of the files and changes that occurred till then.
Is there an option just to list all of the files that will be present till that day together with the files and changes from previous days like when extracting them one by one?

I have used the --list option but it only gives the files that are in side a specific archive.